# Working with spa services in .NetCore 3.0?

Tags: webpack, server-side-rendering, .net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-3.0

I develop SPA web applicaton using ASP.Net Core React+Redux.

After update to .Net Core 3.0 I see that UseWebpackDevMiddleware and AddNodeServices is obsolete.

I learn new project-template React+Redux, but it isn't use webpack or SSR.

1) Where I can find example or information of work with webpack in .Net Core 3.0? with UseWebpackDevMiddleware was realy easy to configure HMR and webpack build.

2) Where I can find example or information about SSR with .Net 3.0 + React?

Answer (score 5):

I feel I am in the same boat as yourself!!!  Having spent the last week or so since the official release of dotnetcore3, I've tried to get something up and running that uses a SPA framework.

Given there has been no answers for this and I am keen to get SPA services running for `aspnetcore3` I have looked into the various templates supplied within Visual Studio.  Currently the templates are `Angular` and `React` that use `aspnetcore3`.

Prior to this there are templates for `Angular`, `React` and also `Aurelia`.  For me Aurelia looks great - vanilla typescript bindings.  So I am trying to go down that route.

I managed to get `HMR` (Hot Module Replacement) working.  I built an Aurelia project using the CLI.  However, my project has a lot of configuration, and I am still learning `WebPack`.  HMR does not currently work with Aurelia CSS.

For my scenario, I had the client app loaded in VS Code.  I created an aspnet core project which then hooks into webpack.

I know you are asking specifically about React, but the concept could be the same.

### Some code

You can find my code here:

https://github.com/andez2000/spa-apps/tree/master/aurelia-cli/e1/aurelia-app

NOTE: Currently I am just dumping stuff into this repo.  There are projects created from the templates if you navigate to the top level.

#### Usage

1. Open folder `spa-apps\aurelia-cli\e1\aurelia-app` in `VSCode`
2. Open the `project.csproj` in `VS2019`
3. Open a terminal in `VSCode` and run `npm start -- --hmr` and wait for output to complete.
4. Compile and run the solution in `VS2019`

This should open the default browser and load the index.ejs.

#### Things to note

The port numbers in the dotnet project and the aurelia project must tie up.

**Startup.cs**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    ...
    app.UseSpa(spa =>
    {

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:5000");
        }
    });
}
```

**aurelia.json**

```
  "platform": {
    "hmr": false,
    "open": false,
    "port": 5000,
    "host": "localhost",
    "output": "wwwroot/dist"
  },
```

So maybe this is conceptually the same as React.  For some reason my React template fails to connect to IIS Express - and it worked the other day - so not really in a position to go digging.

For me, this project has a lot of moving parts.  I wish I had a minimal working solution - that comprises webpack + scss + some spa framework + dotnetcore3.  But there is a tonne of configuration and lots of files.

### Other links

Also it might be worth checking this blog post out:

https://www.alexdresko.com/2019/07/09/htmlwebpackplugin-asp-net-core-3/

Read more about aurelia here:

https://aurelia.io/

Hopefully someone will give you a better answer - but this might get you going.  Hopefully Microsoft will update the docs and examples and provide us with some better guidance.

### dotnet template updates (April 2020)

I am hoping updated templates might overcome the aspnet core/dotnet core differences with webpack. So hoping it's a case of pulling in new templates.

See here:

https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/aurelia-spa